# Error when attempting to launch Robot Framework, process cannot be cast

Tags: eclipse, robotframework

I am using Eclipse 4.6.3, and plugins RED and PyDev. I get this error when attempting to run my robot program.

**An internal error occurred during: "Launching Robot Tests".
org.eclipse.debug.core.model.RuntimeProcess cannot be cast to org.robotframework.ide.eclipse.main.plugin.launch.IRobotProcess**

I do not know if this is related to my code, or some other problem in eclipse?
I can supply more information if needed. And my program did work last week.

Everything is updated, which is when the problem appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like RED 0.7.6 introduced an incompatibility in Eclipse Run/Debug configurations:
https://github.com/nokia/RED/releases/tag/0.7.6

The release notes say to remove old entries from the Run/Debug configurations.